# VSCode Jupyter Extension: Can't find new kernel after updating Julia?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, julia, ijulia-notebook

I'm using the new Jupyter extension for VSCode insiders, and it worked great until I updated Julia (from 1.5.1 to 1.5.3). VScode will run plain .jl files without issue and correctly locates Julia 1.5.3, but the "Jupyter" extension hasn't located the new kernel and tries to use 1.5.1 (now deleted), so I can't run any .ipynb files.

How do I teach Jupyter where the new kernel is?

EDIT: My workaround has been to make a copy of the folder containing "Julia 1.5.3" and rename it "Julia 1.5.1" to make the old path work. This works, but I'd obviously prefer to update the path to the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

When you switch kernels, you need to make sure you have "IJulia.jl" installed in the new Julia environment. See here for more details: https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl#quick-start

Comment: I already have, so alas that wasn't it. But thank you though.